# How can I post a comment with Discord.py without the use of events?

Tags: python, heroku, twitter, discord, discord.py

I'm writting a Discord bot with Discord.py. What I am trying to write is a bot that grabs a picture from reddit, saves the image id in Discord and posts the image to twitter. I use Discord because I am hosting the bot with Heroku and it does not allow to save images or text files. I thought it was a clever way to keep track of the images that the bot picks by posting the images id in a private Discord server

My problem is that every time Heroku restarts the bot I need to post a command on Discord to make it start again. I think there should be some way to avoid this but after reading the Discord.py docs I could not find any solution that allows to read and print comments on Discord without the use of events that require manual inputs.

Comment: Please try to shorten your code only to those parts which are important. E.g. if the problem does not appear within the while block, you dont need to include that whole block, just write something like `while True: ...`

Answer (score 1):

If you bind your code to a command, obviously you always need to call this command after the bot restartet.

Use the `on_ready()` event to call your code everytime your bot starts:

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():

    # CODE

    channel = await client.fetch_channel(YOUR_CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send(OUTPUT)
```

Comment: Yep, it took me a while to get all the permissions correct but that is the way. Thanks!